# Using OrganizationServiceContext to update a different custom entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Can I use the existing OrganizationServiceContext for a plugin to update an entity other than the current target entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and if you're running pre or post transaction (not pre-validation) it'll be included as a part of the SQL transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the extra info about the SQL tranaction!